# Spring Tool Suite 4: How do I turn off Spring Boot Language Server output to the console window?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Somehow I've gotten logging turned on for the Spring Boot Language Server (both 1 & 2). The nasty thing is that when it logs to the console window, all other consoles seem to be deleted. For example, if I do a Run/Test on a project and get a bunch of console output, then go try to edit some code, I will sometimes get some stuffed logged to the console window with Spring Boot Language Server 1 (or 2) showing just above the console output pane. Unfortunately, either this seems to wipe out all other consoles or just switch to come other console mode. I note that the console window icons change and the X and XX icons are missing for deleting individual consoles and they are replace with a little textbox icon with a little red x in it. In order to go back and check the java code for the debug, I have to rerun the test.

How do I either turn off the feature or mute the language server 
console?

Maybe a better way to phrase it, is where do I put the properties to affect the logging of the language server. They don't go in my project's application.properties do they? I think I have the levels set there to prevent them.

Comment: I am looking for same. Create multiple process and take up 500MB of ram. Eating up lot of memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I thought I had looked before. When I bring up Preferences and search for Language Servers STS it brings up the page to turn of the various Language Server consoles.

Answer (score 2):

Just disable debug console for Spring Language Server.

[image: Eclipse Settings for Sping Language Server]

OR

Spring Tool Suite 4,
Version: 4.19.1.RELEASE

[image]