# Spring Boot Language Server keeps loading that slows down everything, I am using STS version 4.19

Tags: spring, sts

Spring Boot language server keeps on loading rewrite recipes and don't know how to stop it, it slows down the sts and pc as well

I want to stop this not sure how to do that,since it is the newer verison i.e 4.19 so I am not getting any relavent answers for this version

Answer (score 0):

Just disable debug console for Spring Language Server.
You can find answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74129805/2451062